# i want to branch instruction processing in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
case LIKE_POST_SUCCESS : {
            const postIndex = state.mainPosts.findIndex(v => v.id === action.data.postId);
            const post = state.mainPosts[postIndex];
            const Likers = [{ id: action.data.userId }, ...post.Likers];
            const mainPosts = [...state.mainPosts];
            mainPosts[postIndex] = { ...post, Likers };
            return {
                ...state,
                mainPosts,
                singlePost : {
                    ...state.singlePost,
                    Likers : [{id : action.data.userId}, ...state.singlePost.Likers],
                }
            };
        }
```

I want to find `singlePost` in `LIKE_POST_SUCCESS`, but I can't use `if` in reducer. I want to use `singlePost` like a function, but in `mainPage` `singlePost` is null, so using it like a function doesn't work. I think something like this should work

```
if (sinlgePage null) { ...state, mainPosts~~~} else { singlePost : { ...state.singlePost, Likers~~ } }
```

but I don't know how to do this in page.

---

This is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jinne202/maplebird) you can see code in front - reducers.

Comment: I made an attempt at rewriting this post to improve its English, I hope I didn't change its meaning by mistake. Feel free to correct any mistakes I might have made.

Comment: you can try to use ternay operator.

`singlePage === null ? { ...state, mainPosts~~~} : { singlePost : { ...state.singlePost, Likers~~ } `

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: yes! `...state.singlePost === null ? {
                    ...state,
                    mainPosts
                } : {
                    ...state.singlePost,
                    Likers : [{id : action.data.userId}, ...state.singlePost.Likers],
                }`

i can solve like this~~~

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use `if` in reducer

That's not correct. You can use *any* conditional logic that you want in a reducer: `if`, `switch`, `for`, lookup tables, loops, anything you want.  A reducer is just another function.

(Side note: you should switch to using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which will let you simplify that reducer logic considerably.)